# Eslint rule tester throws error on arrow function

Tags: javascript, eslint

On putting valid test cases, I added a test case with an arrow function
`var foo = (bar) => bar;`
But on running tests, I'm getting this error.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: A fatal parsing error occurred: Parsing error: Unexpected token >
    at runRuleForItem (/Users/lakshya/Desktop/projects/my-eslint-plugin/node_modules/eslint/lib/rule-tester/rule-tester.js:559:13)
    at testValidTemplate (/Users/lakshya/Desktop/projects/my-eslint-plugin/node_modules/eslint/lib/rule-tester/rule-tester.js:605:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/lakshya/Desktop/projects/my-eslint-plugin/node_modules/eslint/lib/rule-tester/rule-tester.js:885:25)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Try this ...var foo = (bar) => { bar };

Comment: Or if it's just above case then you can use.. var foo = bar ? bar : null;

Comment: maybe it's conflicting with some syntax error above this line?

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar so I tried putting `var foo = bar ? bar : null; ` and it went fine but changing to an arrow function `var test = (props) => props ` the same error came, and I don't think it's cause of something, maybe the parser isn't expecting me to use arrow function or what I don't know, I saw eslint plugins using arrow functions in their rule tests?

Comment: Can you add the error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes I'll add all resources.
https://gist.github.com/lakshyabatman/9d7c7e25863fbc3c9be043418d22ee66 Here is the full error.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to add valid test case in line 20 of this file https://github.com/lakshyabatman/Eslint-Comment-Box-plugin/blob/main/tests/lib/rules/description-before-functions.js

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure the rule tester to accept ES6 syntax, as arrow functions were not included in ES5 and eslint's default parser is ES5.

You can find [an example here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/tests/lib/rules/arrow-body-style.js#L18) of configuring `RuleTester` properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues trying to use template literals (backticks) in the code passed to `RuleTester`.

This worked for me:

```js
const ruleTester = new RuleTester({ parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: "latest" } });
```